# capture an image from camera

Tags: python, face-recognition

since the camera of my laptop doesn't work I want to use the camera of my phone and capture an image
I want to use this captured image to compare it to a database contains face
I already built the database and load convert it to rgb and encoded
the only issue is the camera
so is there a way to use my phone camera and capture an image so that I can compare it to database

Comment: Add your phone type and os information

Comment: it may need to install some program on phone which will have access to camera and it will share image using WWW server. And later you may use Python to access image from this server.

Comment: can you show me how to do that and capture an image from phone camera

Comment: you have to search some application in Google Play (for Android). Without application you would have to write own apllication - and this would need to learn Java and this is complex task.

Comment: using Google `android access camera from other computer` I found article [4 Best Apps to Remotely View a Webcam on iOS and Android](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/software-reviews/4-best-apps-to-remotely-view-a-webcam-on-ios-and-android/) and this can be your start.

Comment: This is defently not face-recogmition issue. Misstagged.

Comment: Actually, maybe this question  as is would  better asked at: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ than here